# GWT rpc not works without internet connection in local machine, but with internet it works

Tags: gwt, rpc

I implemented an rpc call. It works on local machine but does not work without internet connection (like turning off the wifi connecion or LAN connection), although internet is not necessary for the simple call. I am not using google app engine. In the client side, it returns onfailure method "rpc....statuscode:0", and no other errors. Why? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you going to 127.0.0.1 ? Have you tried pinging 127.0.0.1 with and without internet connection ?

Comment: i never ping, it it required because it always comes with 127.0.0.1:8080 port, i will check it and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i uninstalled my xmpp (apache server) then it woked.the reason is now clear xmpp was holding the localhost..